# Convert TZ type of date to java date

Tags: android, timestamp

I'm getting time stamp from the server like- "2014-03-05T13:00:07.341Z"

I want to set this to android calendar and convert the time stamp to am/pm. I have done the following code-

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta");
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
dateFormat.setCalendar(cal1);
try{
    cal1.setTime(dateFormat.parse("2014/03/05T13:00:07.341Z"));
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not able to convert to am/pm . How to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert *to* a specific format, you should use a separate `DateFormat` for that. Currently you've only shown code to parse, and that just returns a `Date` - an instant in time.

You'll need to work out everything you need about your output format - how do you want to represent the date, for example, and which locale do you want to use?

Some sample code to be adapted:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
// Explicitly set it to UTC...
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
Date date = outputFormat.parse("2014/03/05T13:00:07.341Z", Locale.US);

// TODO: What format do you want, and what locale?
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a");
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
String text = outputFormat.format(date);
```

It's not immediately clear what you *should* do if there's a `ParseException` by the way - but you almost certainly *shouldn't* just log it and continue as if nothing had happened.

Note that the Calcutta time zone is only relevant on *output* - the input already specifies that it's in UTC.

Comment: So after converting it to string I have to call Calendar's setTime() method which will set the time and this method accepts a Date object. But when I try, new Date(String) is depricated.

Comment: @user3201291: No, you don't get `Calendar` involved at all. Or rather, if you *do* want to end up with a calendar then your talk about "convert to am/pm" is odd, as that's a *string representation* issue; not something provided by `Calendar`.

Comment: Hey I tried it but it says "2014-03-06T13:00:07.341Z" This date is Unparseable. So the date object remains null. I don't understand why is it so.

Comment: @user3201291: The `date` *local variable* isn't null - it doesn't have a value at all if an exception is thrown. However, I've spotted why: your text has milliseconds in, but your pattern didn't. I've fixed that in my answer.